Applying armature rotation across all frames
Summary
How do I apply a bone rotation to an armature across all frames in the scene?
I am working with static armatures, which are obtained by importing a .bvh motion capture file that I manually edited to contain just a single frame. I want to then rotate specific bones in the armature, which I do by rotating them in pose mode de and then selecting "Apply Selected as Rest Pose". This seems to apply the rotation to the frame in the scene that is currently selected, but when navigating to another frame in the scene and even when I then navigate back to the frame I adjusted the position in originally the pose is reset. How do I make the armature remain pose across all frames in the scene?

This sound like a XY issue. What do you try to achieve in the first place? Applying a pose as rest pose effectively edits your armature, this shouldn't be used as a way to edit animation. Using layered animation via the NLA or just offering curves in the graph editor would be more appropriate . Though I don't know if bvh data makes this different.

Concretely I am trying to extract the bone rotations using the python api to run them through other software I wrote. I do this with something along the lines of:
armature = bpy.data.objects['sample']  for bone in armature.pose.bones:     rotation = bone.rotation_euler()     ...
I have found that adjustments made to the rotations of bones in the armature are reflected in the floats I extract with this script when I rotate a bone in pose mode and then select  "Apply Selected as Rest Pose". Perhaps there is a better way to do this, should I apply something in the graph editor?
